# objective-c how to get private Method lists

Tags: ios, objective-c

as the title,I want to know the private method list of an objective-c class. such as "_resetViewController" for UIviewcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `objc/runtime.h`, in particular the `class_copyMethodList()` function and the `method_*` functions that go with it.

Or if you're looking for a developer tool and not trying to write one, search for `class-dump`.

**Note:** Do *not* ship applications that call private methods, stick to the ones that are documented. Many of these methods may just be a convenience for the developer implementing the public methods, and they will change them when they make additions to the public code. They may remove the methods entirely, or just change the type of a parameter, and if your app calls them, it will suddenly crash, or corrupt memory and make something else crash 5 hours later and you'll have no idea why it is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

```
I try to use runtime log the method list as follow:

- (void)testPrivateMethod {
    Class clz = [self class];
    unsigned int methodCount = 0;
    Method *methods = class_copyMethodList(clz, &methodCount);
    printf("Found %d methods on '%s'\n", methodCount, 
    class_getName(clz));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < methodCount; i++) {
        Method method = methods[i];
        printf("\t'%s' has method named '%s' of encoding '%s'\n",
               class_getName(clz),
               sel_getName(method_getName(method)),
               method_getTypeEncoding(method));
    }
    free(methods);
}
```

but,I just got three method as follow:

```
Found 3 methods on 'HGMThirdViewController'
    'HGMThirdViewController' has method named 'testPrivateMethod' of encoding 'v16@0:8'
    'HGMThirdViewController' has method named 'viewDidLoad' of encoding 'v16@0:8'
    'HGMThirdViewController' has method named 'didReceiveMemoryWarning' of encoding 'v16@0:8'
```

Comment: you may need to fetch the _properties_ as well, optionally not only on the instance-level but on the class-level too.

Comment: Have you tried calling the same method on the superclass of your  class? I think it only gives you methods added at the level of the class you are examining, not inherited methods, so you'd have to loop until `clz.superclass` is `nil`.

Comment: Also, as @holex hinted: To get the class methods, call `object_getClass()` on the *class itself*.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few regularly updated repositories containing the headers - here's a good one (for academic purposes only of course ): https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers

As @uliwitness mentioned, it is dangerous using private APIs in production code.